# can if be a proper function rather than a special form

Tags: function, lisp, functional-programming, special-form

I finally started learning functional languages (emacs lisp) and it makes explicit distinction between functions and special forms such as flow control , for example if.

Is there a fundamental/theoretical reason why special forms are distinct from functions?  do any languages provide functional `if`?

Thanks

Comment: This was a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069669/can-if-statements-be-implemented-as-function-calls

Comment: On a side note - While emacs lisp is fun because you can manipulate Emacs with it, it's old as languages goes. You might want to play around with something more modern, such as scheme.

Comment: @troelskn: You should have just called elisp "crappy" instead of "old". GNU Emacs Lisp (1985: http://www.jwz.org/doc/emacs-timeline.html) is about 10 years younger than Scheme (1975: http://library.readscheme.org/page1.html).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With eager evaluation the distinction is required, languages with lazy evaluation (i.e. Haskell) if et al. can be functions.

Eager evaluation: The function's arguments are evaluated *before* calling the function, and only the results are passed to the function.

Lazy evaluation: A function's arguments evaluated if and only if they are accessed.

Comment: Well, I never did anything in Scala, so I don't know any details.  Still, I expect one has to specify whether an argument is evaluated lazily or not -- or does call-by-name have some other semantics?  If yes, if you could provide a link beside the pure reference, I'd be very thankful.

Comment: I think the underlying attribute is that of pure functionality: in a purely functional language, or in code using only pure functions (functions which return a value but have no side effects), `if` can be a function.  Haskell's lazy evaluation is necessary for its functional purity.

Comment: Well, I always associated the _pure_ in "pure functional" with "no side effects possible" (except the I/O part...).  It never came to me that lazy evaluation is _required_ for a pure functional language.  Well, just another white place on my programming map...  Somehow I start contemplating on giving up on all those issues.

Answer (score 8):

If [`if`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_if.htm) was a normal function, then both its arguments—the *then form* and the *else form*—would *both* be evaluated *before* calling the `if` function, because that's the rule of [function evaluation](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_ababc.htm): evaluate *all arguments* to produce values, then provide that sequence of values as arguments to the function designated by the first symbol in the list.

Instead, with `if` what you want to do is evaluate exactly one of the *then form* and *else form*, not both. In order to suppress evaluation of one or the other, you need either a macro or a [special form](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_s.htm#special_form).

Answer (score 3):

In languages like Emacs Lisp and Common Lisp, special forms are built-in language constructs.  They have different evaluation rules that normal function calls. For normal function calls all arguments are evaluated. So, you can't write an IF as a normal function - the condition determines which clause gets evaluated. Also usually you can't write your own special forms - in Common Lisp there is no language construct for defining a special form (though individual implementations must have implemented the existing ones somehow. This leads to macros. With macros you can write a syntactic transformation that transforms one expression into another one. To be able to write IF as a macro, you need to have another conditional form, which you can use for the transformed code. Lisp provides conditionals as basic constructs. Let's assume COND is such a basic construct, then you could expand IF into a usage of COND.

MY-IF as a macro in Common Lisp:

```
(defmacro my-if (condition true-clause false-clause)
   `(cond (,condition ,true-clause)
          (t ,false-clause)))
```

So

```
(my-if (foo-p) 'one 'two)
```

gets expanded into

```
(cond ((foo-p) 'one)
      (t 'two))
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No.

Long(er) answer: (if ...) requires that you control the evaluation order of the arguments. Lisp, being an eager language cannot do this in a function.

Workaround: do it in a macro:

```
(defmacro _if (cnd true false)
    (let (  (gcond (gensym))
            (gresp (gensym)))
        `(let ( (,gcond ,cnd) ;`#quotes
                (,gresp nil))        
            (and ,gcond       (setf ,gresp (multiple-value-list ,true)))
            (and (not ,gcond) (setf ,gresp (multiple-value-list ,false)))
            (values-list ,gresp))))
```

For example:

```
[dsm@localhost:~]$ clisp -q
[1]> (defmacro _if (cnd true false)
    (let (  (gcond (gensym))
            (gresp (gensym)))
        `(let ( (,gcond ,cnd) ;`#quotes
                (,gresp nil))        
            (and ,gcond       (setf ,gresp (multiple-value-list ,true)))
            (and (not ,gcond) (setf ,gresp (multiple-value-list ,false)))
            (values-list ,gresp))))
_IF
[2]> (_if (= 1 1) (+ 2 3) "bar")
5
[3]> (_if (= 1 2) (+ 2 3) "bar")
"bar"
[4]>
```

Comment: I think it would help to post working code in ANSWERs. Not only the syntax of your code is broken, also the logic.

Comment: the logic is not flawed. (and ...) and (or ...) are already lazy. Syntax *was* broken tho.

Comment: Why does (_if t nil 3)  return 3?

Comment: Why does (let ((cond nil)) (_if cond t nil))  return T?

Comment: Why does (defun foo (a b c) (_if a b c)) not compile?

Comment: left as an exercise for the reader ;-)... But, basically, because fixing it so it works in all cases obscures the principle.

Comment: a gensym with the result of cond would fix it when combined to the 'false' expression

Comment: To me it looks like your OR/AND logic simply does not work. (_if t nil 'false) returns false instead of NIL. A basic IF that does not work is no IF, I'd say.

Comment: That's a bit better. I don't think you need the PROGN. In Common Lisp it is still not IF, since in Common Lisp (if t (truncate 3 4) t) returns 0 3 . In your macro it returns only 0.

Comment: I think multiple values would be taking it a bit too far

Comment: but fixed it anyway :) and took out the (progn ...) too

Comment: My problem with this is that you're saying IF doesn't have to be a special form, but you're using AND.  You can't get from the standard CL function (which evaluates everything) to IF (which doesn't evaluate everything) with macros (unless, of course, the condition can be evaluated at compile time).  You need something that looks like a function but isn't, which in CL is a special form, and you can build from there.  Since the original question was why special forms were necessary, and the IF was just an example, I just don't see this as an answer.

Comment: Have you read the text (rather than just the code) of the answer?

Answer (score 1):

For completeness: there are no special forms in the [Pico](http://pico.vub.ac.be/) language for example, and `if` is a primitive *function* while Pico is inspired by Scheme and has eager evaluation by default.

In Scheme you could write

```
(define (true t f)
  (t))

(define (false t f)
  (f))

(define (function_if c t e)
  (c t e))
```

and then

```
(function_if true (lambda () 'true) (lambda () 'false))
==> true
```

What makes this manageable in Pico is that you can define *functional parameters* that take functional arguments that are "automatically" delayed. This means that you don't have to do the wrapping inside lambdas yourself. Pico therefore has eager evaluation but with lazy evaluation on demand, bypassing the need for special forms.

So, in Scheme syntax with functional parameters you can encode booleans as:

```
(define (true (t) (f))
  (t))

(define (false (t) (f))
  (f))
```

Then function if becomes:

```
(define (function_if c (t) (e))
  (c (t) (e)))
```

and

```
(function_if true 'true 'false)
==> true
```

As another example, the definition of the function `and` is `(define (and p (q)) (p (q) false))`.

Similarly you can define `or`, `not`, `while`, `for`, ... as functions, using the above encoding of booleans.

Answer (score 0):

In Scala it's possible to model `if` with correct side-effect evaluation using call-by-name arguments.

```
def If[A](cond : Boolean, truePart : => A, falsePart : => A) = if (cond) truePart else falsePart
```

These feature can be used to model lots of [new control structures](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/138) as well.

Answer (score 0):

IF could be a function in a functional language having call-by-name semantics (lazy evaluation), as in Lambda Calculus or Algol. In fact that is, I think, at the heart of the relationship between [Turing Machines and Lambda Calculus](http://www.cyberconf.org/~cynbe/muq/muf2_42.html) as equivalent foundations for computing. However, in languages having side-effects (like assignments to variables) it is not much use, because *when* things happen is important.